# given code not showing Interestitial Test ad ? which code i missed

Tags: android, admob, adsense

Given Code i tryed  .  which logic i missed ?

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            //********interstitial
            mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
            mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            mInterstitialAd.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `show()` your InterstitialAd instance **when it has already been loaded**.

So remove the line `mInterstitialAd.show();` from `onCreate`, and do like this to check an ad `isLoaded()` in the `onCreate`:

```
mMyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
            }
        }
    });
```

Note that you must prepare `mMyButton` to be usable (add it in your layout.xml and `findViewById` it before `setOnClickListener`).

Then, click the button to test.